# How to make the mouse only change point only when clicked in the same window?

Tags: mouse, point, events, selected-window

I want to change the mouse behaviour in Emacs:

When I click **between windows** (i.e. from one window into another)), I only want to select the new window and not change point. This is the behaviour globally enabled through:

```
(progn
  (global-set-key [mouse-1] 'mouse-select-window)
  (global-unset-key [down-mouse-1])
  (global-unset-key [drag-mouse-1]))
```

When I stay with my mouse click **in the same window** I want Emacs' out-of the box behaviour with moving point and selecting on drag, i.e.

```
(progn
  (global-set-key [mouse-1] 'mouse-set-point)
  (global-set-key [down-mouse-1]    'mouse-drag-region)
  (global-set-key [drag-mouse-1]    'mouse-set-region))
```

Is there a standard way to do this? I have tried to provide my own customised function for `[mouse-1]` but somehow this is not enough.

Comment: Show us your custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what i came up with.

The trick is that, as you already seem to figured it out, `[down-mouse-1]` will cause probles, as it will also select the window, so when it comes to `[mouse-1]`, the new window is already selected.

I first wrote a handy utility function:

```
(defun gpolonkai/event-in-current-window-p (event)
  "Check if EVENT happened in the current window."
  (eq (selected-window) (posn-window (event-start event))))
```

Then, in all mouse button handling function, you can check if the event happened in the currently active window:

```
(defun gpolonkai/mouse-set-point (click &optional promote-to-region)
  "Set point based on click location.

If CLICK happened in an inactive window, select that window without setting point"
  (interactive "e\np")
  (if (gpolonkai/event-in-current-window-p click)
      (call-interactively 'mouse-set-point)
    (call-interactively 'mouse-select-window)))
```

Now unbind `[down-mouse-1]` and bind this function to `[mouse-1]`, and you are all set! Also, don’t forget to `(require 'mouse)` to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the advice mechanism instead. It doesn't affect clicks on links and buttons, though, which would require advising `push-button`, `widget-button-click` and potentially other functions.

```
(define-advice mouse-set-point (:around (f event &optional promote-to-region) disable-clickthrough)
  (let ((window (posn-window (event-start event))))
    (if (eq window (selected-window))
        (funcall f event promote-to-region)
      (select-window window))))

(define-advice mouse-set-region (:around (f start-event) disable-clickthrough)
  (let ((window (posn-window (event-start start-event))))
    (if (eq window (selected-window))
        (funcall f start-event)
      (select-window window))))

(define-advice mouse-drag-region (:around (f start-event) disable-clickthrough)
  (let ((window (posn-window (event-start start-event))))
    (when (eq window (selected-window))
      (funcall f start-event))))
```